# Akka long-running initialization and crashing actor from within Future callback

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor that is responsible for talking to a web service. I order to talk to the service, the actor needs to fetch an authorization token. The token expires on a regular basis so the actor also needs to regularly check if the token has expired and fetch a new token.

My questions:

What is the accepted way for doing some long-running task that may fail in the constructor? In my example, my actor cannot be considered "ready" until it has successfully received a token from the remote service. This could fail and should be re-tried.

How should I handle the case where the service is unreachable, stopping me from getting a new token. I'd like to throw an exception which is handled by my supervisors strategy (some sort of throttled restart policy)

This is basically what I have right now:

```
case object CheckAuth
case object AuthFailed
case class UpdateAuth(token: Token)

var auth: Token = Await.result(authorize(), 2.seconds) // throws if server cannot be reached or i'm denied

val tick = scheduler.schedule(10.seconds, 10.seconds, self, CheckAuth)
override def postStop = tick.cancel()

override def receive: Receive = {
  case AuthFailed    => throw new Exception("Auth failed")
  case UpdateAuth(a) => auth = a
  case CheckAuth => {
    if ( authHasExpired() ) {
      authorize() onComplete {
        case Success(r) => self ! UpdateAuth(r)
        case Failure(e) => self ! AuthFailed // this feels dirty
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid doing that stuff in the constructor. Use two states (unauthorized and authorized) and then switch the receive method via `context.become` to toggle back and forth between the states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to model this is to have two states for the Actor, either explicitly or implicitly. The choice between these depends on how client interaction with this Actor shall look like:

- either the Actor answers requests negatively while no token is available, or
- the Actor stores requests in the absence of a token and answers when that becomes available.

The explicit model uses `context.become()`:

```
class A extends Actor with Stash {
  def auth(): Unit = {
    authorize() pipeTo self
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(2.seconds, self, AuthTimeout)
  }
  def update(token: AuthToken): Unit = {
    context.become(running(token))
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds, self, CheckAuth)
  }

  auth()

  def receive = initial
  val initial: Receive = {
    case UpdateAuth(token) =>
      unstashAll()
      update(token)
    case AuthTimeout => context.stop(self)
    case _ => stash()
  }
  def running(token: AuthToken): Receive = {
    case CheckAuth => auth()
    case AuthFailed => context.become(initial)
    case UpdateAuth(token) => update(token)
    ...
  }
}
```

The implicit model stores a `var token: Option[AuthToken]` in the Actor, starting out at None.

Concerning handling of failures: you can do whatever you wish, I suggest stopping the Actor and letting the supervisor re-create it after a given time—restarts as per the supervisorStrategy are always immediate.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you happen to have a link to more resources showing common akka patterns?

Comment: We describe some in the documentation, but more can be found using Google (meaning that the information is distributed across many excellent blogs). Jamie and I are also writing [Reactive Design Patterns](http://manning.com/kuhn) but we are just starting with that part of the book.